# Proper terminology for group representations

Tags: matrices, group-theory

I have a question about the terminology of representation theory.

Consider some group $G$. Suppose that its elements are represented in terms of matrices with given characters. Performing a similarity transformation on such matrices does not change their characters. The transformed matrices are also a representation of the group with the same characters.

Is it common/acceptable to refer all sets of matrices with the same character as "**a** representation of the group", or does "**a** representation" always refer to a specific choice of matrices?

Comment: Are you talking about equivalent representations of a group?

Comment: Maybe. I just mean, if I have a representation and do a similarity transformation on it, is that a different representation or another expression of the same representation. In other words, is "a representation" fully determined by the characters.

Comment: Strictly speaking, a representation of a group $G$ is a homomorphism ${\rm GL}(n,K)$ for some field $K$ and $n \ge 1$. But it is indeed common practice to use the term "representation" to mean any one of an equivalence class of representations. It is acceptable provided that both you and the person or people that you are addressing are familiar with this convention. The fact that you are asking the question at all suggests that you should avoid doing this!

Comment: The people I speak with usually would not have a problem with this but I wanted an idea of how it is in Mathematics